# Report progress of long running process from WebAPI to client

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a Blazor website, using the hosted Blazor template (so WASM front end with WebAPI backend all on .Net6).

I have an API call that is expected to take several minutes to complete and I'm looking for a reliable way to communicate the progress back to the client.

I've been looking at SignalR, but from what I can see it's not intended to be used purely for Server to Client communications, more between Clients with the Server simply hosting the hub.

I thought about using multiple API calls - one to initiate the job, one (on a repeating timer) to get progress, and one to get the results. That should work, but it feels like a bit of a hack to me.

Is there a better way? Can anyone point me to a real working tutorial? Most of the tutorials I can find seem to concern themselves with monitoring the progress of uploading a large file which I don't think is relevant to what I'm doing.

BTW, I'm still learning Blazor and this is my first time going really beyond messing with the OOB templates, so pardon me if I've missed something obvious.

**_Edit**

Thanks for the comments, looks like I was on the right track previously, I must have just missed something out because I tried again, and I've got it mostly working. The only bit that I can't yet figure out is how to restrict the progress messages to just the client that initiated the API call. There doesn't seem to be an option for _hubController.Clients.Caller like there is from with the Hub itself.

See https://github.com/Slugsie/BlazorReportProgress for my current minimal sample project.

Any help on restricting the responses to the calling client would be greatly appreciated.

**_Edit 2**

I figured it out, or at least I got it basically working how I need it to. I've updated the project on GitHub accordingly.

Comment: That's the job of SignalR. `it's not intended to be used purely for Server to Client communications` that's wrong. In fact, Blazor Server uses SignalR to send all screen updates to the client

Comment: Adding to @PanagiotisKanavos comment on the server your service/controller can Inject `IHubContext<YourHubClass>`.

Comment: If the client has a UserId join them to a group of the same name stringified. They will be the only one in it. Send message to that group. That or your need to somehow track their connectionId with the request. You can add "salt" to the stringified userId for a bit more security.